# Azure AD Enterprise Application - Identify Caller Application

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a REST API which uses Azure ADD App registration to allow other apps to call it.

In the Azure Portal, I have registered it as an Enterprise Application and also registered the consumer applications and assigned them Roles appropriately.

The authentication and RBAC works fine.

But the use case that I am working on requires me to identify and log the incoming request calling application's name (The one seen in the portal as 'Display Name', when we view the list of users and groups for an enterprise Application).

As advised in the internet, I am using some Identity related API to read the claims from the request header.

```
var provider = claimsUser.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider").Value;
var sid = claimsUser.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
OR
var sid = claimsUser.FindFirst("stable_sid").Value;
```

But this gives me a GUID value which I couldn't map to any of the consumers of the Enterprise Application.

The clients are all registered in the Azure portal.

In the Portal, I can see the apps in the "Users and Groups" section for  the Enterprise application, with their appropriate roles.

In terms of usage, before making the call, the clients generate a bearer token based on the certificate that they get from Azure. The make the call with the bearer token attached to the request header. This bearer token is validated against the Azure AD, in the filters set before every controller..

What I want is to get are the details about this client who has made the call.. As per some repliers, and, to which I agree, the Guid that I get as part of the previous call mentioned above is for the actual user and not the app itself which is making the call.

Can anyone throw some light into it.. some code snippet will be of real help..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what authentication flow you are using, but SID is generally for a user that's logged in, not an application. if your client applications are using client id and secret, the token it returns that you send to the api should include the app registration guid. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#access-control-lists . So the appid and iss should give you the guid of the app registration. using this, you can make a call to graph api, to identify the display name of the app registration. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

If your app is a user login app, and you don't want to make a call to graph, the other option you could do as a workaround would be to create app roles and assign users to them but name the app roles with some convention that includes the app's display name. then the name could come through under roles claim.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps

those are some options.. but other than calling graph or kinda working around to inject the name into a different claim of the token I'm not sure of any other method to get the "app registration's display name"

Comment: Added some more details to the initial post.. Maybe that will make it easier to answer.. Can u share any code snippet..